# Cryptocurrency compile error

Tags: mac, compiling

I'm compiling a SmallChange clone on Mac OS using the .osx makefile, and I get this error. What should I do?

'boost/assign/list_of.hpp' file not found

Answer (score 1):

[Install boost.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104322/how-do-you-install-boost-on-macos)

See the [instructions](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/master/doc/build-osx.md) if you have additional problems.

Comment: Can I get db48 set up with homebrew instead of macports?  I get the error: fatal error: 'db_cxx.h' file not found

Comment: I think I fixed the above error. Getting now: unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md) DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER;

Comment: @meecoder That's outside of the scope of this question. However, I made a new question. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/30502/deprecation-error-on-mac