# Deprecation error on mac

Tags: mac, compiling

I'm compiling on mac, and I get this error:

```
unsigned char *SHA256(const unsigned char *d, size_t n,unsigned char *md) DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER;
```

Why does this happen, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mac OS X 10.7, Apple wants you to use their own crypto library instead of OpenSSL. This is pretty unlikely to ever be done by the bitcoin devs, so here's how to turn the warning off:

When running `./configure`, give it the following argument:

```
./configure CXXFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated-declarations
```

This will disable the warning.

Comment: Only in 10.7? Then you're out of luck (with me). Only 10.6 and 10.9 here.

Comment: No need to edit `./configure`, usage: `./configure CXXFLAGS=-Wno-deprecated-declarations`

Comment: @Bitcoin_1o1 Thanks, edited.